# Wrapping C++ modules in Java

Tags: java, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface, swig

I've inherited a project, originally written in `C++`. 
Due to implementation requirements, I need to either re-write the project in a JVM based language, like `Java` or `Kotlin`, or simply wrap the existing code in a `Java` or `Kotlin` (RESTful) API.

The existing code base is also entangled with an *very* old network simulation framework.
I'm therefore leaning heavily towards untangling the simulation framework and wrapping the `C++` code using something like **JNI** and **SWIG** to implement in a non simulated environment.

I'm wondering if **JNI** and **SWIG** are still the best options available?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't rewrite the C++, and I'd still go the JNI route. If you have the budget hire a JNI C++ expert contractor for a month as the learning curve is quite steep - you need to use lots of guard-type idioms for object references; strong and weak and what you end up with is perfectly readable C++. I don't like SWIG as you tend to end up with an unsupportable mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping with JNI (or SWIG) requires a clever definition of the API. See a nice explanation [here](http://videocortex.io/2017/salami-method/). There exist some C++ frameworks that make JNI operations easier on the C++ side, consider them early, before you get too deeply invested in reference management. From what you write, it may be necessary also to provide some Java interface *below* the C++ layer, e.g. we use the the Java network APIs on Android, even from C++ code.